In C#, How to dispatch to 2 different generic functions depending on the supertype of input generic type?
Considering the following code:

    public static class TypeChecker
    {
        public static string CheckType<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T).IsValueType ? HandleValueType<T>() : HandleReferenceType<T>();
        }

/*
compilatioon error looks like this:
1>Pure.cs(9,44): Error CS0453 : The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TypeChecker.HandleValueType<T>()'
1>Pure.cs(9,67): Error CS0452 : The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'TypeChecker.HandleReferenceType<T>()'
*/

        private static string HandleValueType<T>() where T : struct
        {
            return $"This is a value type (struct): {typeof(T).Name}";
        }

        private static string HandleReferenceType<T>() where T : class
        {
            return $"This is a reference type: {typeof(T).Name}";
        }
    }

The compiler wasn't able to relate typeof with the constraint imposed by the 2 private functions, which explained the error. What's the easiest way to make it work?
I'm using C# 9.x but solution on higher versions will also be appreciated

You can do some magic with static generic classes, fields in them and expression trees (the main idea though is to use some reflection to build corresponding generic call via MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))):
public static class TypeChecker
{
    private static class TypeCheckerInternal<T>
    {
        private static Func<string> _handle; 
        static TypeCheckerInternal()
        {
            // todo - prettify/optimize getting methods
            var handleReferenceType = typeof(TypeChecker)
                .GetMethod(nameof(TypeChecker.HandleReferenceType), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);  
            var handleValueType = typeof(TypeChecker)
                .GetMethod(nameof(TypeChecker.HandleValueType), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var method = typeof(T).IsValueType
                ? handleValueType.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T))
                : handleReferenceType.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(Expression.Call(method));
            _handle = expression.Compile();
        }

        public static string Handle() => _handle();
    }

    public static string CheckType<T>() => TypeCheckerInternal<T>.Handle();

    private static string HandleValueType<T>() where T : struct
    {
        return $"This is a value type (struct): {typeof(T).Name}";
    }

    private static string HandleReferenceType<T>() where T : class
    {
        return $"This is a reference type: {typeof(T).Name}";
    }
}

For every type T passed to TypeCheckerInternal<T> it will have it's own _handle field which is effectively caching for the reflection/expression tree compilation so this relatively heavy code will be run only once per type per application lifetime.
AFAIK currently there is no language construct which allows to "pass through" the constraints after the type check. See:

Expose a way to bridge generic constraints @github
Proposal: Type extracting patterns @github
Proposal: Pattern match via generic constraint @github


wow ... that's a lot of reflection. Will it make the invocation slow and hard to maintain? This answer can be accepted as-is but let's wait for a few weeks for shorter answers

"Will it make the invocation slow " @tribbloid it depends on the usage patterns, if the call is made once per type - then relatively yes, but you should not bother since the call is made only once, if there are a lot of invocations with the same type - then no, reflection is used once per type and then all calls use the compiled code (as it is explained in the part of the answer after the call).
